# "Access is Denied" from one PC, but not the other

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth

I'm using the following code to create a connection to the Google Drive API:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
      string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
      credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

      try
      {
            this.credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                  GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                  Scopes,
                  "Google Drive Import",
                  CancellationToken.None,
                  new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
            log.Error("Exception caught in creating Drive connection" + ex.InnerException.Message);
      }
}
```

This seems to work okay with creating a connection from my PC (compiled/executed in Win10 with VS 2015), but when I try from a server (compiled/executed in Windows Server 2012 R2 with VS 2015, I get "Access Denied" when debugging. What am I doing wrong here?

So far, I've compared logs from Fiddler on both PC's, and I see all 200's result codes from both workstations.

Comment: are you running this as an installed application on a server?

Comment: I don't think so. They're both using the same code from source control.

Comment: Let me try again What type of application is this?  the code you are using is for a installed application it will not for example work hosted on IIS as web application.

Comment: Yes. this is a windows forms application, not a web application.

Comment: check that you have access to credPath on the server. you need to be able to write to that directory.  While you are at it check that you have access to read client_secret.json

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo , I will check as soon as I get to work.

Comment: If needed you can move the location of the datastore.  http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/  if it still doesn't work give me the full error you are getting.

Comment: I followed your guide on changing the datastore, to just "C:\Temp\", and I'm getting the same "Access Denied" error. As for the JSON file, it's set to "copy always", and gets it from the debug folder. When I step through, it passes the using stream part, so access to the JSON file seems okay.

Comment: "Access Denied" isnt an error with the library i think you should post the full error you are getting. EX:  "System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path 'Google.Apis.Auth' is denied."   Is the library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146661/discussion-between-rudy-m-and-daimto).

Answer (score 0):

@DaImTo helped me figure this out. It was an issue with the rights to writing the  file to the credPath location. In the comments, you'll find a link to help change to a custom dataStore: [daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified](http://daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified)  . Thanks again @DaImTo.